# configure gedit to always open in new window

Tags: gedit

I would like to configure gedit so that everytime I double click on a text file it will open on a new window instead of a new tab. How can this be done?

Something like,

```
gedit --new-window "file name"
```

, but with a double click

Using ubuntu 12.04 with cinnamon, and gedit - Version 3.4.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `gedit` setting called `notebook-show-tabs-mode`, which is usually set by default to 'always', which means every new document opened will open in a tab. However, if you set it to 'auto' by entering the command below in the terminal, `gedit` will not open in a tab unless another document is currently open.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui notebook-show-tabs-mode 'auto'
```

However, if you want to make sure that no tabs are ever opened, choose the 'never' setting, so that is probably what you want. You may then need to use the *File* menu within `gedit` to switch between documents, although `gedit` will still warn you when you try to close it if there are still unsaved documents. This is the command you want in this case:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui notebook-show-tabs-mode 'never'
```

To return to the default settings, use 'always' in the command above instead. You can also find the whole list of hidden settings for `gedit` by entering

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i gedit
```

but I think the `notebook-show-tabs-mode` setting is maybe the one you want.

---

However, after considering your comment, I think you could also use the standalone (`-s`) `gedit` option, as that will open each new document in a new window. Create a `.desktop` file like this and make it executable  and put in `~/.local/share/applications`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=gedit_alternative
Comment=gedit standalone
Exec=/usr/bin/gedit -s %U
Terminal=false
GenericName=
```

Then simply associate it with text files by editing `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and add the following to these sections of the file (backing it up first):

```
[Default Applications]
text/x-log=geditspecial.desktop
text/plain=geditspecial.desktop
```

and

```
[Added Associations]
text/x-log=geditspecial.desktop;
text/plain=geditspecial.desktop;
```

Replace `geditspecial` with the name of your own `.desktop` launcher. Now when you click text files they will all open in separate instances.

Comment: this no longer works on trusty and higher

Comment: 'notebook-show-tabs-mode' is now 'called show-tabs-mode', but it does not do the job in my case

Answer (score 10):

I also need this. I suddenly find simpler solution:

```
sudo nautilus /usr/share/applications/
```

Point to **gedit**, hit *Alt+Enter (Properties)*, and replace command to

```
gedit -s %U
```

Tested on Xubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This works but also opens every new file MAXIMIZED. Causing the new instance to cover the entire screen

Comment: To clarify, the file you want may be called `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop` rather than `gedit`, and you need to change `Exec=gedit %U` to `Exec=gedit -s %U` in this file.

Answer (score 5):

### For Nautilus and other GUI instances

Edit your `/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop` file add the argument `--new-window` to the `Exec=` entry:

**Change from:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=gedit
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=gedit %U
Terminal=false
```

**Change to:**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=gedit
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=gedit --new-window %U
Terminal=false
```

### For the commandline

That takes care of the `nautilus` and other `gui` instances.  For the commandline use the `alias` in `~/.bashrc` as mentioned by [Leocadio González Casado](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219046/configure-gedit-to-always-open-in-new-window#comment1491902_319248) above.  Append this to your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
alias gedit="gedit --new-window"
```

*Note:

This works with all Ubuntu versions.*

Comment: maybe its better to copy the '/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop' file first to '~/.local/share/applications/gedit.desktop' first and modify the copied version. You can change additionally. This just overwrites the configuration for the current user

Comment: In 22.04 I had to also change `DBusActivatable=false` in that Desktop Entry file. Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1225659/986830

Answer (score 1):

Very good feature for multimonitor configuration to look at the one file and edit other.
But some time we may use single window configuration. To use both:

1. Run (as it described by user2223633): 
    
    `sudo nautilus /usr/share/applications/`
2. Point to gedit and create a copy (ctrl + c, ctrl + v).
3. Rename the copy to a name understandable for You.
4. Point to new gedit copy.
5. Hit Alt+Enter or RightClick -> Properties (as it described by user2223633).
6. Replace command to (as it described by user2223633): 
    
    `gedit -s %U`
7. Close the Nautilus window (opened by root) as soon as possible.
8. Open a Nautilus window or use Desktop and point to any text file
9. Rightclick it and point to Open With - Other program.
10. If You see both gedit and it's copy the configuration is finished. If not press "Show other program" and open the file with gedit copy.
11. Repeat 9 and 10 opening by gedit not by copy.

Now You can open file using both modes using Rightclick - Open With - Other program.

Tested by Ubuntu 13.04 X64

Answer (score 0):

In my installation of Ubuntu 14.10, once gedit is opened, right click on the launcher icon will display a selection list. The first entry in the list is, "Open a New Window".

That works for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in the command line just add the following line to you `~/.bashrc`

```
alias gedit="gedit --new-window"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS=

sudo nautilus /usr/share/applications/

right-click Text Editor > Open with Other Application > Text Editor

(you need gedit.desktop not org.gnome.gedit.desktop) > change-

gedit %U

```
to
```

gedit -s %U