# Gedit always opens documents in new windows instead of tabs on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, gedit

I can't open new documents in tabs by clicking by mouse in the file manager. I searched for this issue but only found [old](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960589/configure-gedit-to-always-open-documents-in-new-tab) questions for old Ubuntu versions. I changed `DBusActivatable` to `false` as the answer suggested. I still have the problem.

My OS version in 18.04.1 LTS and up to date.

Isn't opening with tab instead of windows default configuration?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The "old" question is less than a year old. Have you tried the solution there? If so, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1074941/edit) and update your question and indicate what you have tried and what results you get.

Comment: It didn't work.