# gedit open second file onwards in a new window. Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gedit

In Ubuntu 18.04 when I open a second text file, it opens in a new window out of the box.

In Ubuntu 19.10 when I open a second text file, it opens in the existing window with new tab.

I have tried the answers in this post [configure gedit to always open in new window](https://askubuntu.com/q/219046/739431) but no success.

How can I achieve this in Ubuntu 19.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this link https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/ If the .desktop file has the Entry `DBusActivatable` set to `true` It will ignore the `Exec` line.

> DBusActivatable:
>
> A boolean value specifying if D-Bus activation is supported for this
>   application. If this key is missing, the default value is false. If
>   the value is true then implementations should ignore the Exec key and
>   send a D-Bus message to launch the application. See D-Bus Activation
>   for more information on how this works. Applications should still
>   include Exec= lines in their desktop files for compatibility with
>   implementations that do not understand the DBusActivatable key.

Ubuntu 19.10 has this entry `DBusActivatable=true` for gedit .desktop file which is `org.gnome.gedit.desktop` file..

This answer is just a workaround because just to make the Exec key to work in this case.. I am making the `DBusActivatable=false` with out knowing the advantages of this key (https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/#dbus) and its implementation in newer versions of Ubuntu starting from 19.10.

Ok now we set the `DBusActivatable=false` this means `Exec=` line will work.

So in my case I have changed

```
Exec = gedit %U
```

to

```
Exec = gedit --new-window
```

from `man gedit` you can choose the options for `[Desktop Action new-document]`

```
   --new-window
          Create a new toplevel window in an existing instance of gedit.

   --new-document
          Create a new document in an existing instance of gedit.

   -s, --standalone
          Run gedit in standalone mode.
```

Comment: THIS RIGHT HERE IS THE ONLY ANSWER ON THE INTERNET THAT WORKS FOR UBUNTU 20.04 THAT I CAN FIND. I had to set "DBusActivatable" to "false" as per above before the "-s" override would work EVER. Now my gedit windows open as new windows when I open a file! THANK. YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop` by changing the following line :

```
Exec=gedit %U
```

by adding the `--new-window` option :

```
Exec=gedit --new-window %U
```

It would define to always open `gedit` on a new window.

P.S : Here is my entire `gedit.desktop` file with this option, that worked well on 18.04 :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=gedit --new-window %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=gedit
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TextEditor;
X-GNOME-DocPath=gedit/gedit.xml
X-GNOME-FullName=gedit Text Editor
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gedit
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.28.1
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-ExtraInfoScript=/usr/share/gedit/gedit-bugreport.sh
Actions=new-window;new-document;
Keywords=Text;Editor;Plaintext;Write;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gedit

X-AppStream-Ignore=true

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=gedit --new-window

[Desktop Action new-document]
Name=New Document
Exec=gedit --new-document
```

You can note that the *New Document* option won't open a new window, you can add again this `--new-window` option to it (so it would be `Exec=gedit --new-document --new-window` instead of `Exec=gedit --new-document`)